# How to align custom cell in row of Table View-left or right-IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have some custom cell as .xib which has the following objects:

1. `UIButton`
2. `UILabel` with background

My issue is I want to align right the button type cell in and left align the label type cell.

How can do this?

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Take one cell and align label and button on  them instead of aligining cells.

Comment: How can i do this in code?does cell has some alignment attribute?

Comment: Put Label & Button in one cell not need to use two cells. 
Put Label as Left align & Button as Right align. 
Based on cell Hide & Show Label & Button. 
Like
if (indexPath.row%2 != 0) {
Button.isHidden = NO;
Label.isHidden = YES;
}
else  {
Button.isHidden = YES;
Label.isHidden = NO;
}

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you define it in different `.xib`? If you do this align
   operation in some cell, it will be more simpleness. Just use auto
   layout.
2. But if you need do that really, just load `button.xib` file at `UILabel .m` and
   frame it like this `CGRectMake(-button.frame.size.width, 0,
   button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.Height)`

*If there some word you could not understand, forgive it. Because my English is bad.*

Comment: Thanks for reply,I needed to add some background for label and other style for buttons.Therefore i decided to use .xib file.I have added an image of desire result please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

oh my god! I have no see the image. It may be Chinese gateway made..
You can do like this:

1. TableView A has two different cells: cellButton、 cellLabel. Cells
   has some width.
2. In `cellButton.xib`, set constant of `UIButton` right align to `self`,<`self` is UIButtons super view: `cell.contentView`>
   and CenterY to `self` constant.
3. In `cellLabel.xib`, set constant of `UILabel` left align to `self`,
   and CenterY to `self` constant, too.
4. Refresh tableView

There are auto layout, I hope you can understand. ^_^